# Group by grouping sets wtihout including all columns selected

Tags: sql-server

I have 4 columns: AccountNumber, Company, Batch, and Amount. I want to sum(amount) by Company and Batch but not by AccountNumber as AccountNumber is always unique and this wouldn't really accomplish anything. Is there a way using grouping sets to sum(amount) by Company and Batch but not by AccountNumber while still displaying AccountNumbers in the results set?

Thank you

Comment: How would you want the account numbers displayed?  In some sort of delimited list column on the grouped row?

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast answers everyone! I guess I should have mentioned that I was hoping to use the group by grouping sets functionality to include the subtotals for company, batch. So, batch 1 company 1 would have a subtotal and batch 2 company 1 would have a separate subtotal. Every row that was being summed together for the subtotal at the bottom would appear as company, batch, accountnumber, amount without any aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this kind of problem requires a sub-query and a join.  It is easy to understand if we think of the problem as two steps:

This will sum by company and batch:

```
select company, batch, sum(amount) as sum_amount
from atable
group by company, batch
```

Now just join that to your account numbers

```
select atable.accountnumber, subq.company, subq.batch, subq.sum_amount
from (
    select company, batch, sum(amount) as sum_amount
    from atable
    group by company, batch
) subq
join atable on subq.company = atable.company and subq.batch = atable.batch
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.Company, b.Batch, b.AccountNumber, s.Total
from baseTable b
inner join
(
    select Company, Batch, sum(Amount) Total
    from basetable
    group by Company, Batch
) s on s.Company = b.Company and s.Batch = b.Batch
```

This will do it, but does give the total on each line. Not really any way to prevent that, though.